# Convertir String a arreglo

Tags: javascript

Tengo un String como el siguiente:

```
var sArray="[0, [6, 2], null, 7, 1]";
```

Sin embargo quiero convertirlos a tipo arreglo, debido a que cuando itero de la siguiente forma:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=1) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Me imprime carácter por carácter del String.

Comment: Saludos, haz intentado reemplazar las ""?

Comment: No puedo, en realidad estoy haciendo una función que recibe una variable, solo sé que siempre me mandarán un String con la estructura de un arreglo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curiosamente `[0, [6, 2], null, 7, 1]` es json válido así que podrías usar `JSON.parse` y sólo eso:

```js
console.log(JSON.parse("[0, [6, 2], null, 7, 1]"))
```

Answer (score 0):

De esta manera lo podrias hacer:

```
var sArray="[0, [6, 2], null, 7, 1]";
var nuevo = JSON.parse(sArray);
var newarray = [];

    $.each(nuevo, function(i, val) {
        newarray.push(val);
     });

alert(newarray);
```

Comment: Si pase devuelve ya un array, todo el proceso posterior es innecesario